# Website showing differently in windows xp and mobile

Tags: html, css

I made a website for one of my clients, and I change the background and font color.

Now on windows xp and smartphones the background changed color to the default color and the fonts remained the same.

The website is [simfest.ro](http://simfest.ro/)

I don't know what to do to make it work on windows xp and smartphones.

Comment: OK. So `background-color` is defined as `#000000` (black) - what should it be? Where have you put style definition that you expect to work for `body`?

Comment: The background should be black, but when the site is opened on windows xp, it is white + white font.

Comment: I cannot see it, sorry - I have Windows 7, but that shouldn't affect it - try it on different browsers, clear cache (Ctrl+F5), it must work.

Comment: I contacted 3 people with windows xp and they all see white background and white fonts. They all cleared cache. The same thing happens on mobile devices. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Comments should be used to request clarification/be relevant to *the post* and not about individuals (those ones have been removed). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background colour changes when the browser width is less than 1200px wide.

You have specified the `background-color` for the selector `.td-grid-wrap` within a media query:

[image: Simfest issue]

What you need to do is move the `background-color` property to the non-media-queried selector `.td-grid-wrap` or perhaps `.td-page-wrap`.

[image: Simfest Fix]

Comment: Thank you, on my mobile device the background color is set correctly, I asked someone with windows xp to help me and see if the site is ok. Waiting for their answer. Thank you Richard once again.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the page, it is not a matter of windows xp I suppose, if you make some test about the media querys, you will see that big screens has the body background color set to #000000 but scaling down to smaller resolution, the background of the single row is white.
review your css rules and take a look at all the media queries.